# How to create a menu in javascript dynamically after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

After click button it will dynamically generate an id for that particular button clicked on the document. ( like a Google gadgets every gadgets has menu option..)
Thing I've to do is... for generated id I've created a menu option as gadget menu options below the button.

this is my code:

```
 var htmlTag = document.createElement("div");

 htmlTag.innerHTML+= "<div style='position:absolute;border:solid 1px black;background-color:white;padding:4px;'>";
 htmlTag.innerHTML+= "<ul ><li><a href=''>Edit</a></li><li><a href=''>Delete</a></li></ul>";
 htmlTag.innerHTML+= "</div>";
 alert(htmlTag);
 $("#"+submenuid).html(htmlTag);
```

submenuid is dynamically generated id... for button..

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function makeIt(submenuid) {
  var htmlTag = document.createElement("div");

  htmlTag.innerHTML+= "<div style='position:absolute;border:solid 1px black;background-color:white;padding:4px;'>";
  htmlTag.innerHTML+= "<ul ><li><a href=''>Edit</a></li><li><a href=''>Delete</a></li></ul>";
  htmlTag.innerHTML+= "</div>";
  var submenu = document.getElementById(submenuid); 
  submenu.appendChild(htmlTag); // non-jquery, comment and uncomment next line for jquery version
  // $("#"+submenuid).html(htmlTag);
  return false;
}  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="x"></div>
<a href="#" onClick="return makeIt('x')">Make</a>
</body>
</html>
```